# How do I get access to Castle Windsor's Fluent Interfaces API?

Tags: api, castle-windsor, fluent-interface

I've been having tons of problems getting the non-xml configuration for Castle Windsor set up working properly.  In the meantime I've seen more and more people giving advice via the Windsor Container fluent interface.  I've been Gooogling about for the last day and I cannot find this API anywhere.

I am talking about the key .Register() method which seems to be an extension method to the IWindsorContainer object.  It seems like it might be in the Castle.MicroKernel.Registration namespace, but I cannot find the corresponding library anywhere!

Also, is there any place where I can find documentation for this stuff?

---

**EDIT:**
I found that the copy of Castle.MicroKernel in the [sample project here](http://rhysc.blogspot.com/2008/08/masstransit-classic-webforms.html) has more namespaces then the one I was using (even though this one is eight days older and v1.0.0 whereas mine is v1.0.3...), still having trouble finding the .Register() method or any samples though.

**EDIT:** 
I found some [fluent interface samples at Bitter Coder](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,6c1a25f7-5c8c-4a5e-bda9-04ffa944ebd0.aspx), no downloadable samples though so I'm still at a loss.

**Edit Again:** Finally got it.  The most recent source code for castle windsor is available [here](http://builds.castleproject.org/cruise/DownloadBuild.castle), get the most recent successful build, inside the zip file is a bin directory.  The fluent interface is inside Castle.Microkernel (you will probably need to reference Castle.Dynaproxy, Castle.Dynaproxy2 and Castle.Windsor too).

PS This post is the #1 Google result for "castle fluent interface documentation" sad guys, you need to get on that.  *Crickets chirp* What's that?  Fine.  Let me figure this out then I'll get on it then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Fluent interfaces were introduced a while ago - but are only available on Trunk (after RC3) either grab the castles sources (from the projects subversion repository) and build the IoC projects yourself from [here](http://svn.castleproject.org:8080/svn/castle/trunk), or easier still grab the [latest successful build](http://builds.castleproject.org/cruise/index.castle) on the continuous integration server and use that.

**Castle.MicroKernel.Registration** is the name space you'll need to use, in the MicroKernel assembly - once you have a reasonably fresh build of Castle you should be able to find Register(...) methods on both IKernel and IWindsorContainer interfaces, allowing the application of "registration components" (anything which implements IRegistration) which includes the various fluent component registration features in Castle, as well as anything custom you might develop.

The best place to ask questions regarding Castle is the google [castle-project-users](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users?hl=en) and [castle-project-devel](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel?hl=en) groups - keep an eye out for Craig Neuwirt in particular as he's the core developer working on the fluent interface features in Castle Windsor, and so is best equipped to answer questions about the various fluent interface features, as they are not widely documented yet.

Comment: Oh good god, I have to download and learn how to use NAnt first?  What is it with you Alt.Net guys?  I've spent the last 3 months getting up to speed on your tools and I'm nowhere close to 'getting it' yet

Comment: The build server has compiled binaries, there's no need to learn Nant or how to build the project itself - just download the latest binaries from there.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so just for reference. Official, complete documentation for the API is on [Castle Windsor Documentation Wiki](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Fluent-Registration-API.ashx)